# python: search in list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search

I want to iterate over a list of lists of dictionaries:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'sravan'},
    {'name': 'bobby'},
    {'name': 'ojsawi', 'number': '123'},
    {'name': 'rohith', 'number': '456'},
    {'name': 'gnanesh', 'number': '123'}
]
```

Furthermore I want to check each entry if there is a key number where the value is `123`.
If so, I want to append the value of name of this entry in a new list
which would be `'ojsawi'` and `'gnanesh'` in the above case.
Else, I want to append 0 in the new list.

This means, the final `new_list` with the appended values should look like this:
 `new_list = {0, 0, 'ojsawi', 0, 'gnanesh'}`

I have tried different versions/possibillities with 2D for loops and lambdas etc. but I think the main problem is that the lists have different sizes. Any help/tipps would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it with list comprehensions with a nested if/else in it:

```
new_list = [x.get('name') if x.get('number') == '123' else 0 for x in data]
```

Outputting:

```
[0, 0, 'ojsawi', 0, 'gnanesh']
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than list comprehensions, you can also do it using `map()` and functional programming if you want. Note that `map()` returns an iterator which generates things as you go if you are using a `for` loop, so if you want the entire result immediately, use `list()` around your `map()` function.

```py
def zerofilter(my_dict):
    number = my_dict.get("number")
    if number != "123":
        return 0
    else:
        return my_dict.get("name")

data = [
    {'name': 'sravan'},
    {'name': 'bobby'},
    {'name': 'ojsawi', 'number': '123'},
    {'name': 'rohith', 'number': '456'},
    {'name': 'gnanesh', 'number': '123'}
]

print(list(map(zerofilter, data))) # output is [0, 0, 'ojsawi', 0, 'gnanesh']

# You can also do this:
for res in map(zerofilter, data):
    print(res)
```